# Why does up navigation close the app instead of directing to parent activity even though parent activity is specified in manifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have set up my manifest xml to indicate the parent activity, yet the navigation up button in the action bar simply exits the app instead of directing to the specified parent activity.

I have already tried using meta-data tag, still the same result.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

```
<activity
     android:name=".RegisterActivity"
     android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
     android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity">
```

There is nothing special about LoginActivity and RegisterActivity.The RegisterActivity is started by the LoginActivity using intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem too, override onOptionsItemSelected to solve that

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //return to your parent activity
            return true;
     }
}
```